# Which is the better of these two code fragments

Tags: java

```
//first
if(num % 2 == 0 ) {
  isEven = true;
}


//second
isEven = (num %2 == 0);
```

What is the best thing to do, and is first case a case of code smell?

Comment: Never branch when an assignment will suffice.

Comment: Never branch when /a readable, maintainable/ assignment will suffice. Just adding that in there because people sometimes takes "hard rules" to extremes :)

Comment: You can eliminate the parentheses - `isEven = num%2==0;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They don't do the same thing - if `num` is odd, the first leaves `isEven` with its previous value, the second sets it to `false`.

I would:

- Try to initialize the variable at the point of declaration, and not change it afterwards.
- Use the second form in preference to the first in general.

When the body of an `if` block is *just* setting a variable, and the value can be expressed as some *simple* modification of the condition of the `if` block, and you *always* want to set some value, I would just use the simple assignment.

The same goes for `return` statements - I would rather have:

```
return (num % 2 == 0); // Or (num & 1 == 0)
```

than

```
if (num % 2 == 0) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing anything about the surrounding context, these two version actually differ in their semantics.

The first version will only change the value of `isEven` if `num` is an even number. The latter version will *always* update the value of `isEven`. So I would definitely prefer the latter, as it ensures `isEven` holds a useful semantic value.